# Include a specific file in prod ng build

Tags: angular

I am developing an application where my client side is written in angular 6 and backend in dot net core WebAPI.
I have created a setting.ts file that includes the URL of the WebAPI. Local URL is different than Prod URL.Each time I am deploying I need to change the URL in setting.ts. This is cumbersome.

I am wondering is there a way where I can create two setting file one for Dev and other for Prod and include Dev setting.ts only in Dev build and Prod setting.ts only in Prod build.

Comment: setting.ts? don't you mean environment.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is the `environment.ts` and `environment.prod.ts` files. You can also add more environment files based on your number of environments. For example: UAT.
then you will use the following option to specify to build for which environment:

`ng build --environment production` for angular 4 or `ng build --configuration production` for angular 8. use `ng build --help` to know which syntax to follow.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The URL of the backend was in a setting.ts so  i had to manually change it every now and then. I moved the URL to the to the environment.ts and it worked fine.Thank you for your suggestion @Mu'men Tayyem